# ¿Cómo hacer un formulario para insertar datos y una tabla que muestre datos de la base de datos en una sola vista en MVC?

Tags: mvc, datatable, foreach, crud, model

Estoy haciendo un CRUD en MVC y quiero hacer una vista que tenga un formulario para insertar datos a la base de datos y una tabla que muestre los datos insertados en una sola vista, este es el encabezado de la vista:

```
@model Console.Models.Product
@{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
```

Este es el formulario de inserción:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
                                            {
                                                <div class="box-body">
                                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                                        @Html.Hidden("productID", 0)
                                                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductName", @id = "txtProductName" } })
                                                            </div>
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productName, "", new { @class = "text-danger", Type = "productName" })
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productQuantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductQuantity", @id = "txtProductQuantity" } })
                                                            </div>
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productQuantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.productColor, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @name = "txtProductColor", @id = "txtProductColor" } })
                                                            </div>
                                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.productColor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            }
```

Esta es la tabla que muestra los datos insertados:

```
<table id="Data_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productName)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productQuantity)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productColor)
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productName)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productQuantity)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productColor)
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.productID }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-sm" }) 
                                            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.productID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger btn-sm" })
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><div class="panel-footer">Total = @Model.Count()</div></th>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
```

El problema es que hay un error en la tabla que muestra los datos que dice que debería usar IEnumerable en el modelo de la vista (Console.Models.Product) pero al usarlo ahora hay un error en el formulario de inserción. ¿Hay alguna forma de tener los dos en una sola vista?